# Make MySQL database accessed by just one user

Tags: mysql, permissions

I have MySQL server, and it have a lot of databases and users, and i need to create a user and a database for it, and only this user can access this database, even the root user can't access this database.
how can i do it

Comment: Is this DB going to be backed up routinely any as well? What level of access is this one user supposed to have to this one DB? I thought typically root could only access the DBs from the local OS MySQL is installed and not remotely via a client workstation, etc. Restricting root seems like overkill since the server OS machine the DB is installed will still allow local admins access to the correlated flat files to the see the data, restore on another MySQL instance, etc. If the flat files on the server are accessible by server admins, they can likely still access data without root credentials.

Comment: Why do you wish to do this? On what operating system?

Comment: do you mean to say that you want to create a database lets call the DB name as "vault_db" that has usernames and passwords corresponding to databases in to a table? And have only one user called "vault_user" to access database (vault_db) not even root. Is this is what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You need an 'admin' for maintenance, etc.  You don't have to call it 'root' and you don't have to let everyone know the password.

It is 'best practice' to grant user(s) access to one (maybe more) database(s).  In this context, a "user" could be a human, or the login for an app.  Example:

```
 GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON dbname.* TO username@"1.2.3.4" IDENTIFIED BY "...";
```

That implicitly does not give that user (from that host) access to any other databases, nor privileges such as `CREATE DATABASE` or `GRANT`.

When writing Stored Routines, carefully think about the use of `SECURITY INVOKER` versus `SECURITY DEFINER`.  `INVOKER` means that the routine cannot do more than what the user could manually do.  `DEFINER` lets the routine be more powerful.  This can be useful for providing some otherwise-restricted operation to mere users.

(Caveat:  Newer versions of MySQL have "Plugins" and "Roles" that are more involved than the old `GRANT`; these let you have more involved security models.)

Comment: right, I need that 'admin' user, but when i create that admin and create a database for it via phpmyadmin, mysql automatically grant access for other users that have global privileges to this database, can i remove this users and just keep the admin?

Comment: You can use the mysql commandline tool instead of phpmyadmin.  Based on what you say, that UI is "helping" you get into trouble.